# How to get the full name of a member

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Consider that I have a `MemberInfo` object of member `MyObject.Field1`, how  would I get the full name of this member? I understand that `MemberInfo.ReflectedType.FullName + '.' + MemberInfo.Name` would do, but is there any more "native" solution? I would rather not define notations myself. I have also seen notations like `MyObject+Abc` as a reference to delegates so I am careful.

Comment: `MemberInfo.ToString()` not working?

Comment: No. It will just give the short definition of the member inside the type.

Comment: The notation `TypeA+TypeB` is the CLR notation for `TypeB` nested in `TypeA`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `MemberInfo.ReflectedType.FullName + '.' + MemberInfo.Name` is fine(till someone provides elegant way). I'd use string.format to make it bit cleaner

```
string fullMemberName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", member.ReflectedType.FullName, member.Name);
```

`+` notation is used for nested types. In your example if `Abc` is nested type of `MyObject` name of the type `Abc` will be `MyObject+Abc`.